# Java System Properties

Tags: java

What's the difference between "java.version" and "java.vm.version?"

When I use the latter, I get something like "11.3-b02."  What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

The VM version is the version of the VM software whereas the java.version is the version of the java language(i.e. the specification).  The comparison is analogous to the version of the C++ specification (features etc) versus the version of the C++ compiler (build number, etc).  Does that make sense?  If not, I can take a whack at clarifying it more.

regards,
chris

Answer (score 2):

`java.version` is the version of the language implementation. `java.vm.version` is the version of the engine underneath. That engine may have major improvements in performance between what look like minor releases with no change in functionality, so it is versioned separately.

For more detail, here are how *Sun* and *Oracle* describe those options:

[Sun](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) says:

- java.version - Java Runtime Environment version
- java.vm.version - Java Virtual Machine implementation version

Oracle's [JRockit](http://edocs.bea.com/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/sysProp.html) docs are a little bit clearer:

- [java.version](http://edocs.bea.com/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/sysProp.html#wp999422) - This property identifies the J2SE JDK/JRE product version; that is, which version of the JDK or JSE you are running. The version number also appears on the first line of the output and is common to Sun JRE and Oracle JRockit JRE. The information generated by this property appears in this format:

  ```
  <jdk_major_version>.<jdk_minor_version>.<jdk_micro_version>[_<jdk_update_version>][-<milestone>]
  ```

  The value appears in bold in the example version output below:

  ```
  java version "1.5.0_03"
  Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_03-b07)
  BEA JRockit(R) (build dra-45238-20050523-2021-win-ia32, R25.2.0-28)
  ```

  For more information on java.version, please refer to: http://java.sun.com/j2se/versioning_naming.html
- [java.vm.version](http://edocs.bea.com/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/sysProp.html#wp999146) - This property identifies the JVM implementation version. The version ID appear on the third line of java -version output. This ID is the main method to distinguish between JRockit JVM versions. Below are examples from a few different releases of the JRockit JVM

  - JRockit JVM R24.5.0: ari-49095-20050826-1856-win-ia32
  - JRockit JVM 5.0 SP2: dra-45238-20050523-2021-win-ia32
  - JRockit JVM R26.4.0: R26.4.0-63-63688-1.5.0_06-20060626-2259-win-ia32
  - JRockit JVM R27.3.1: R27.3.1-1-85830-1.6.0_01-20070716-1248-windows-ia32

Answer (score 0):

I found the a [forum entry on sun's site](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5275437) that mentions the java.vm.version property being screwed up sometime in Java6.  [Java's docs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) don't mention the java.vm.version property.  IBM [mentions it](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzaha/sysprop2.htm), so maybe it's specific to the JVM you're using, but not part of the spec.